# Where dose LRU cache in python save data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, lru

I'm trying to cache multiple machine learning models (pickle files) at at least 700MB per pickle . After the caching is done, I can't see any significant changes in memory usage, swap memory, or disk. Despite the caching being done and working fine.

Can anyone clarify what is happening and where the data is saved?

Comment: as I know it doesn't cache at start but when you run function. And it keeps only few last results - so it doesn't have to change memory usage. But all depends what you use - but you didn't snow code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.